# Jenkins trigger on Pull request merge?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

When some repository has PR that is merged, how I can
listen to that event and trigger Jenkins job on Merged PR.

Also is it possible with keeping cron job as one of the triggers.

Thanks in advance

Google it, ut there is no script only Jenkins UI, for which I do not have permissions.

Answer (score 0):

These PRs merge on to some branch (likely master). Every time a merge is made onto master (or any other branch), you have the option for the merge to be created as a merge commit. You can then configure Jenkins to detect commits on to master (or the branch you are merging to) so that the build runs automatically.

How you do this configuration depends on the Git repository you are using. You could use webhooks to trigger the build on Jenkins, or if you want to trigger it with a polling based mechanism with cron jobs, that is also possible. Have your job run every couple of minutes and check to see if the master has had a merge commit created into it. If yes, then do a build and update the status of the latest commit with information on whether the build failed or succeeded. Then, every time you poll the branch, you can check if the last commit has a build status. If yes, it means the commit has been built before and nothing needs to be done. If no, then its time to build that commit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to set webhook to listen merge to master branch and base on that trigger build.
Is there any plugin I need for Jenkins, and what is a code in Jenkins script for trigger and what is webhoook url?